# Is the set {$ 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{3}{16},....$} dense in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

Does the set  {$ 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{3}{16},....$} dense in [0,1]. 
I am not sure about that.

I think it is not dense in [0,1] because the set contains rationals of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$, where $m,n\in N$.

Am i correct? If not please give me a proof and also help me to gain intuition. I want intuition and hint rather than proof. Please leave the proof for me. **My question in different from the previously asked question because I'm in need of intuition and the answers there doesn't give me enough satisfaction**.

Comment: You have correctly described the set. Now see if you can understand why you can approximate any number (rational or not) using these numbers. Hint: think about bisecting intervals.

Comment: What definition of density are you using?

Comment: I am asking this question because I'm  need  more sophisticated answers

Comment: @Michele Maschio Rudin's definition. "A subset A of a metric space M is dense if every point of M is a point of A or a limit point of A"

Comment: It will hit every number in the binary number system between 0 and 1. If the binary number system could not represent all real numbers arbitrary well we would have trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Choose $x\in (0,1]$. If you want to approximate $x$ by these numbers in the distance of $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $N$ such that $2^{-N} < \varepsilon$. Then
$$
(0,1] = (0,\frac 1 {2^N}]\,\cup\,(\frac 1 {2^N},\frac 2 {2^N}]\,\cup\,\ldots\,\cup(\frac {2^{N-1}}{2^N},1]
$$
and $x$ is contained in one of those intervals.

Answer (score 0):

**THE ANSWER IS YES**: In fact\

For $x\in[0,1]$ We have 
$$\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor \le 2^nx <  \lfloor 2^nx\rfloor +1\Longleftrightarrow  \frac{\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor}{2^n}\rfloor \le x \le  \frac{\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^n}\\\Longleftrightarrow  0\le x-\frac{\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor}{2^n}\le  \frac{1}{2^n}\to 0$$

Where $$\lfloor a\rfloor =\max\{n\in \Bbb Z: n\le a\}$$
stand for the floor of $a.$

That is $$\frac{\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor}{2^n}\to x,~~~$$
 but $$\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor \in\mathbb N,~~~\forall n\in\mathbb N $$
ie

$$\frac{\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor}{2^n}\in \{ 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{3}{16},....\}~~~\forall n\in\mathbb N $$